# Time limit before new questions can enter the Triage queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-post-review

I am new to SO reviews, so I mainly see new users in the Triage queue. I noticed, that flagged questions turn up pretty immediately in the Triage queue. I personally refuse to label a question of a new user flagged as "unclear, what you are asking for" or "didn't provide a MCVE" as "Unsalvageable" five minutes after the user posted it. They don't know the rules, so they should at least get a feedback and some time to edit their question. Isn't there a minimum time limit, before these new questions can enter the Triage queue?

Maybe this has been discussed before, but I haven't found a topic like this on SO meta.

Comment: But having their question closed **is** feedback and they normally have time to edit it before if gets deleted (if it gets deleted at all).

Comment: @ivami Valid point that a review is not automatically a deletion, giving new users more time to react. And believe me, I don't hesitate to flag a question, if a user didn't edit the question after 30 minutes and a comment. Correct me, if I am wrong, but my default position is to encourage new users, not discourage them. This is my default for experienced users, who should know better.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant flagged questions in the Triage queue.

Comment: Bad questions should be closed as fast as possible. Otherwise it just wastes the time of answerers that go to the question, have to read it just to note that it can't be answered.

Comment: *P.S.: Is it normal that one in ten reviews is an audit or does this frequency decline, when you have higher reputation scores?* - nope, it really doesn't matter what your rep is - audits get served to *everyone* on roughly the same frequency...

Comment: @BDL Well, I have seen quite often that after a comment new users edited their question to make it worth answering. I guess it depends, what the community wants. Is it a clean database of answers or user participation. I see from the votes that it is not the latter.

Comment: @rene averaging it out though across all reviewers - it's roughly the same :p

Comment: @Piinthesky yes you do.. if you fail enough times you get banned from review for some time.. (review ban time increases if you keep failing audits inspite of timeout)

Comment: When I was a brand new user and posted my first question, I didn't know the rules either. That was because I hadn't read through them like I should have. Then my first question was quickly downvoted, and I decided that reading the rules might be a good idea thanks to those downvotes. Now I'm a contributing member of society. Morale of the story? If a new user doesn't know the rules, it's their own fault for not reading them. Getting their question downvoted/closed will let them know that not following the rules is not acceptable, and if they take the hint, their next question will be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I personally refuse to label a question of a new user flagged as "unclear, what you are asking for" or "didn't provide a MCVE" as "Unsalvageable" five minutes after the user posted it.

Then you have no business using that queue.  If you don't want to participate in the moderation of the site, then that's fine, no one is going to force you to, but if you *are* going to participate, then you need to do so correctly.

> They don't know the rules

They were told what the rules were before they posted.  They were the one that chose to ignore it.

That said, I can't imagine that anyone would need to read any rules in order to know that their question needs to be clear and to contain enough information for it to be answerable.  If someone needs to tell you that you need to make your question clear before you decide to actually make your question clear...

> so they should at least get a feedback and some time to edit their question.

That's exactly what closing the question does.  It gives them time to edit their question and for them to improve it.  If they really do fix their question it can be reopened an answered.  The question attracting low quality answers in the meantime will only make it harder for the question to be improved.

> Isn't there a minimum time limit, before these new questions can enter the Triage queue?

That would defeat the whole purpose of the queue. The only reason the queue exists in the first place is to attempt to get help to problematic posts *as soon as possible*, rather than waiting until it's too late.

Comment: Point taken about low quality questions attracting low quality answers. My observation, too. And just to be clear, I don't have any problems marking error message dumps or similar nonsense as "should be deleted". My point was that I have seen several times posts in the queue less one minute after posting, that needed just a little bit more information, but were marked for deletion without even leaving a comment to the user. Anyhow, I got the feedback of the community, I was hoping for. And seemingly I underestimated the possibility that questions can be reopened.